# Converting a pandas multirow dataframe to a single row combining the rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 100 csv files each of which when read by pandas dataframe is like below:

| gyrus | GW | WM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FlRt | 1.2 | 1.0 |
| FlLt | 1.4 | 1.0 |
| TlRt | 1.3 | 1.1 |
| TlLt | 1.4 | 1.2 |

I need to convert programatically this to the form as below

| FlRt GM | FlRt WM | FlLt GM | FlLt WM | TlRt GW | TlRt WM | TlLt GM | TlLt WM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2. | 1.0. | 1.4. | 1.0. | 1.3 | 1.1 | 1.4. | 1.2. |

so that I can merge all the 100 files to form a large single dataframe

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot your dataframe:

```
out = df.set_index('gyrus').stack().to_frame().T
out.columns = out.columns.to_flat_index().str.join(' ')

# Output
print(out)
   FlRt GW  FlRt WM  FlLt GW  FlLt WM  TlRt GW  TlRt WM  TlLt GW  TlLt WM
0      1.2      1.0      1.4      1.0      1.3      1.1      1.4      1.2
```

Comment: that solved my problem !!! thanks a ton.